# PySpark transform dataframe

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, data-cleaning, data-processing

Let's say I have the following data in a dataframe `receipts`:

> Id  |  Fruits
>
> ---
>
> 1   | ['apple', 'banana']
>
> 2   | ['apple']
>
> 3   | ['pear']
>
> 4   | ['pear', 'banana']

And I want to turn that data into a matrix that would look like this:

> | A | B | P |
>
> ---
>
> |  1  |  1 | 0 |
>
> |  1  |  0 | 0 |
>
> |  0  |  0 | 1 |
>
> |  0  |  1 | 1 |

(1 if the fruit is present, otherwise 0)

Does anyone know an efficient way of doing this? My real problem consists of 60.000 "fruits" and over 10 million ids.

Comment: Look into one hot encoder

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer
colorVectorizer = CountVectorizer(inputCol="Fruits",outputCol="Fruits_OneHotEncoded", vocabSize=60, minDF=1.0)
colorVectorizer_model = colorVectorizer.fit(df)
df_ohe = colorVectorizer_model.transform(df)
import numpy as np
x_3d = np.array(df_ohe.select('Fruits_OneHotEncoded').collect())
rows, idx, vocabsize = x_3d.shape
X = x_3d.reshape(rows, features)
X
```

Try the above code.

Comment: I have too much data for calling .collect().
I think I will try to implement a UDF instead of your numpy step!

Comment: collect step is only there if you want the whole matrix. You can remove it and call it for data subset.